# How to zip a list emitted by an observable into another observable?

Tags: rxjs

Let's say I have one observable that emits at an interval of 1 sec. I have another observable that emits at an interval of 3 secs. The second observable emits a sequence of numbers. So every time that the second observable emits a sequence of numbers I want it to be zipped with the first observable.

For example:

| observable 1 | observable 2 | zipped |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 |  | [1] |
| 2 |  | [2] |
| 3 | [10,20,30,40] | [3, 10] |
| 4 |  | [4, 20] |
| 5 |  | [5, 30] |
| 6 | [10,20,30,40] | [6, 40, 10] |
| 7 |  | [7, 20] |

Comment: Unfortunately the arrays in the "zipped" column don't really reflect what you write in the text. Therefore it's unclear what you really want to achieve.

Comment: E.g.: If you zip `of(3)` and `of([10,20,30,40])`  the zipped-array would actually be `[3, [10,20,30,40]]` . Therefore I struggle to understand the logic in your table.

Comment: I don't want to zip the first and second observables, I want to zip the first observable with the emitted output of the second observable, which is an array of numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am not wrong you are searching solution like this:

```
import { timer, combineLatest, Observable, BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

const first$ = timer(1000, 1000);

const second$ = new Observable<number[]>( subscriber => {
    const intervalId = setInterval( () => {
        subscriber.next([10,20,30,40]);
    }, 3000)

    return () => {
      clearInterval(intervalId)
    }
});

// This BehaviorSubject is used like 
// some kind of "state" and keeps the emited 
// array. 
const state$ = new BehaviorSubject<number[]>([]);

second$.subscribe(state$);

combineLatest<[number,number[]]>([
  first$, 
  state$
]).pipe(
    map(([first, second]) => {
        if (second.length > 0) {
          return [first, second.shift()]
        }
        return [first]
    })
  ).subscribe(
  (value) => {
     console.log(value);
  }
);
```

Or at least your table describes it. Here is working stackblitz url:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-ufwqyh?file=index.ts